# Multiply final nodes in a tree

Tags: r, tree, treeview, collapsibletree-r

I am working with a tree, that I created by using `collapsibleTree`.

Each node has a `character` type. I would like to assign to the last nodes also a `numeric` value and then multiply/sum/subtract/divide them, depending on which last nodes are selected by the user.

So, for example, assuming this is the tree:

```
data("cities")
collapsibleTree(
  cities,
  hierarchy = c("continent", "country", "city"),
  width = 800
)
```

I would like to assign to each city a numeric value (e.g. population) and then I would like to have the sum of the cities that are selected by the user. For example, I would like to set Rome = 4 and San Francisco = 1, so that if both Rome and San Francisco are selected by the user, an output is returned stating 'The sum of San Francisco and Rome is 5'.

Is this something doable with the `collapsibleTree` interface?
If not, do you have any suggestions?

[image: San Francisco and Rome example]